# chartjs hover over data without hoveringing on line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When you hover over a specific data point on a chartjs linechart the point's value can be shown. But let's say you hover on the graph, not on a specific data point but over the "empty space". In that case there should be some function to show the values of the points vertically aligned with the pointer. Does any such solution exist?

Basically the reason I'm asking is to be able to make mobile-friendly graphs and it can be difficult/irritating for the user to try and hit the small data points with their fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set `intersect` to `false` in the tooltip config:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        intersect: false
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is very good. But there's one thing: When I try clicking the white space it seems the graph selects the point closest with my pointer, rather than the point vertically aligned with my pointer. For instance, imagine I have 2 values: the first is high and the low, so the second one is painted at the bottom of the canvas. If I click under the first point the graph will sometimes select the second point, because it is simply closer. Is there any way to correct that?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it! :)
I realized I could just set mode to 'index'